# Obtaining a confidence interval for the prediction of a linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, linear-regression

The data I am working with is being used to predict the duration of a trip between two points. There are about 100 different trips in the data and ~90k observations.

I am using the standard pattern:

```
feature_cols = df_features.columns.drop( [ 'log_duration' ] )
X            = df_features[ feature_cols ]
y            = df_features.log_duration

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, random_state = 42 )
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit( X_train, y_train )
linreg.score( X_test, y_test )
```

To perform the regression and obtain my score (~.74).

However, let's say, that it predicts that it will take 40 minutes to make the trip between two points. Obviously, it will not take exactly 40 minutes. What I am looking for is a way to report that it will take 40 minutes +/- C number of minutes for the trip.

Using Pandas and SciKit, how can I obtain C?

Comment: A good description is in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVCQi0KPR0s

Comment: A good read: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6773

Answer (score 10):

You can estimate the standard deviation of your prediction:

`stdev = np.sqrt(sum((linreg.predict(X_train) - y_train)**2) / (len(y_train) - 2))`

Then, for any significance level you want, you should check correspondent Gaussian critical value (for example, for significance level 95% it is 1.96).

Finally, confidence intervals are (prediction - 1.96*stdev, prediction + 1.96*stdev) (or similarly for any other confidence level).

Another approach is to use `statsmodels` package.

Comment: This is a really naive approach.

Comment: I am wondering if we could use the standard error of the coefficients to get the CI of predictions?

Comment: it's kind of impressive how sklearn doesn't believe in the concept of coefficient CI

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a linear regression, you could make use of the method described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147242/how-to-calculate-the-prediction-interval-for-an-ols-multiple-regression). It is quite a bit more complex that the +- standard deviations, but is would be more accurate.